# Using a function, how do I dynamically change the elements of a dictionary corresponding to a variable?

Tags: python

I want to modify the dictionary elements formulaically to the corresponding user input, but I do not know how to do this in a versatile manner by initialising the elements with just perhaps another argument and another block of code.
Bearing in mind, using a dictionary may not be the most simplistic way to do this.

Thanks for any answers.

I have tried to add additional arguments to the first function under class Card: but I am oblivious to how to modify the dictionary elements by using this argument in a formulaic way that is versatile.

```
class Card:
  def __init__(self, t, d, dd):
    self.title = t
    self.desc = d
    self.decision_desc = dd

  def introduce_card(self):
    print(self.title)
    print(self.desc)
    print(self.decision_desc)
    option = input("> ")
    if option.lower in ["y", "yes", "t", "true"]:
      # line to modify dictionary element corresponding to the card to true
    elif option.lower in ["n", "no", "f", "false"]
      # line to modify dictionary element corresponding to the card to false

card1 = Card("title", "desc", "yes/no")
card_ans = {"card1": False, "Card2": False, "Card3": False}

card1.introduce_card()
```

This so for later, I can further programme based on the boolean values stored and use them as conditions.

Comment: I think the best option could be to store the Boolean as part of the class, but assuming there is some reason you cannot, you can reference a dictionary dynamically as long as you have the key. In this case probably self.title is the key, and therefore `card_ans[self.title] = True` would be the idea. You would still need to solve the issue of your dictionary being outside of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it with a list:

```
>>> d1 = {"temp": "val"}
>>> d2 = {"temp": "val"}
>>> d3 = {"temp": "val"}
>>> list = [d1, d2, d3]
>>> list_example = [d1, d2, d3]
>>> for i, element in enumerate(list_example):
...     element["temp"] = i
...
>>> d1
{'temp': 0}
>>> d2
{'temp': 1}
>>> d3
{'temp': 2}
```

Here is some basic code showing how to do it with an input:

```
>>> d1 = {"temp": "val"}
>>> d2 = {"temp": "val"}
>>> d3 = {"temp": "val"}
>>> for i, element in enumerate(list_example):
...     user_input = input("something: ")
...     element["temp"] = user_input
...
something: test1
something: test2
something: test3
>>> d1
{'temp': 'test1'}
>>> d2
{'temp': 'test2'}
>>> d3
{'temp': 'test3'}
```

Here is some basic logic:

```
>>> d1 = {"temp":"val"}
>>> d2 = {"temp":"val"}
>>> d3 = {"temp":"val"}
>>> for i in list_example:
...     user_input = input("1, 2, or 3: ")
...     if user_input == "1":
...             i["temp"] = True
...     elif user_input == "2":
...             i["temp"] = False
...     else:
...             i["temp"] = "error"
...
1, 2, or 3: 1
1, 2, or 3: 2
1, 2, or 3: 3
>>> d1
{'temp': True}
>>> d2
{'temp': False}
>>> d3
{'temp': 'error'}
>>>
```

Should be easy to modify this code to your needs!

Answer (score 0):

My 10 cents is to revisit the design on this.

It seems like the keys in card_ans are based on the name of the variables in your code. So if the variable name changes the result changes? Even if you got this to work to anybody later reading the code this would seem to be totally unexpected.

My suggestion based on what I think you might be doing is to consider creating a CardManager class which is responsible both for the creation/destruction of cards + managing your answer question.  The manager would own the function `introduce_card`.

Answer (score 0):

Objects don't know the names of the variables that reference them. The object can be referenced from multiple variables, or even from things that aren't variables, like list elements. So there's no way for a method in the object to find the dictionary element that corresponds to the variable.

The dictionary keys should correspond to information in the `Card` object itself, such as the `title`. Then you can do

```
card_ans[self.title] = True
```

But it's not clear why you need the `card_ans` dictionary in the first place. Why not just add an `answer` attribute to `Card`?